# Convert/execute scripts from Selenium to QTP

Tags: selenium, qtp

We have an automation framework developed in Selenium. Now, we want to migrate the scripts from Selenium to QTP.I would like to know if there is any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts on selenium were Java, so there is no way apart from manually porting each scripts to QTP.

Another way that you can try is Upgrade to UFT. Now that you have UFT, you will have free access to LeanFT. LeanFT supports Java and C#.
with little tweaking you would be able to switch over.

See this for more details - *http://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/Sel_LeanFT4SelT.htm*

*https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/Selenium-and-LeanFT-Easily-integrating-LeanFT-into-your-Selenium/ba-p/246519?nm#.WR2PCuuGMfI*